# Flickering when drawing to 3d visual model

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a program that using drawing brush to draw the video on a visual model. At first, it works completely fine and no flickering, but after a few compilation and usages, the flickering starts to occur. What is the possible problem behind this? If I migrate to a completely new wpf window project, the  program works fine again and the cycle repeat.

Comment: try to compile it in RELEASE and run like EXE, and not from VisualStudio. See what happens...

Comment: The flickering happens too when I did that..any idea?

Comment: Is it possible to be memory problem?

Comment: no ideas on subject, honestly. Did you check rendering layers with [WPF Performance Suite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969767.aspx) ?

Comment: Hmm..The problem temporary solved after I updated my graphic card driver..I will check for the rendering layers later on..Thanks.